# Why does EnumerateMetafile only work with Aero enabled

Tags: c#, gdi+, system.drawing.imaging

My code [enumerates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.drawing.graphics.enumeratemetafile(v=vs.110).aspx) a metafile:

```
private void Parse()
{
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);
    PointF pointf = new PointF();
    graphics.EnumerateMetafile(_metafile, pointf, ParseCallback);
}

private bool ParseCallback(EmfPlusRecordType recordType, 
    int flags, int dataSize, IntPtr data, PlayRecordCallback callbackData)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

My development machine is Windows 7 `VirtualBox` guest on Ubuntu host.

The code used to work fine. However, when I turned off Aero, the code stopped working: The `ParseCallback` would never be called.

Only when I turned Aero back on, `ParseCallback` was executed again.

Why and how can I make this code work on non-Aero-enabled machines?

Comment: That's a very obscure problem.  You'll surely have to make that metafile available for anybody to have a shot at diagnosing the problem.

Comment: The problem occurs with various EMF+ files. Here's one (a simple diagonal line): http://xltoolbox.sf.net/files/test.emf -- But you are right, the problem is obscure, and I've come to think that I'd rather implement my own metafile reader to enumerate the records.

Comment: I recommend adding graphics.Dispose() to the end of your Parse method, but I have doubts on it being the main issue.

Comment: @Aron Nice! But in fact I made a deliberate decision not to enable Aero -- I dislike the Glass design. Plus, I guess I would have difficulties executing `pc.Install(GeForce.FromStore());` on a virtual machine ;-)

Comment: @bovender Surely you meant `pc.Install(nVidiaFactory.BuildLatestGfxCard());`

Comment: Have you tried under Windows 8 and/or 8.1?

Comment: @SimonMourier desktop composition/"Aero" **cannot be disabled** on Windows 8 and the method works just fine on my 8.1 machine.

Comment: @GrawCube - yep I know it cannot be disabled (some would say its always disabled, dead). The question was precisely whether it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full answer to the "why?" question, but it does not work because you're getting the `Graphics` GDI+ object from the Window handle. Instead, you want to get it from a GDI DC, like this:

```
private void Parse()
{
    IntPtr hdc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero); // get entire screen dc
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHdc(hdc));
    PointF pointf = new PointF();
    graphics.EnumerateMetafile(_metafile, pointf, ParseCallback);
    ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc);
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdc);
```

Note you could also use the Graphics object from the Form `OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)` method, it should also work, just like in the official sample code for EnumerateMetafile method here: [Graphics.EnumerateMetafile Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142060(v=vs.110).aspx)